# basic Unix command not found

Tags: shell, unix

I've installed mysql on my laptop.

Now when I launch a terminal window and a unix command like `grep`, I get this message:

```
-bash: grep: command not found
-bash: cat: command not found
...
```

What's happen ? Do you have skills or any ideas to retrieve my precious unix functions ?

Comment: What does `declare -p PATH` output?

Comment: It sounds like you changed your `PATH` to point just to the `mysql` directory, instead of adding it to your `PATH`. Fix the line in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` that's assigning to `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar you fixed my bug

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to put this in a comment, but I don't have enough reputation, sorry!

Basic Unix commands like grep or cat are most likely in this folder:

```
/usr/bin
```

In order for them to work, you need to have the correct set up of your PATH variable. You might have changed it unknowingly during the installation of mysql. 
You can fix this temporarily by trying something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

This will add whatever you have on your PATH at the moment, all the "normal" routes to your precious unix functions. Try the commands again after executing this line in your terminal, and let us know :)

Comment: Thanks zapatiila, I fixed my bug.